# How to draw the track of the bullet in spiral?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In my paper, I want to describe the track of the bullet in the air. To show the Precession, I want to use a figure like the following:

[image]

But the background of the original figure is not transparent, it seems a little ugly in my paper. So I want to use Ti*k*Z to draw it again. Can anybody in Tex.SE give some tips about the code details?

Answer (score 9):

Welcome to TeX-SE! Yes, such things can be drawn with Ti*k*Z. I store the bullet shape in a `pic` such that you only need to change things once if you want to change this shape.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/bullet/.style={code={
\draw[#1] (-0.5,-0.2) to[out=0,in=-150] (0.5,0)  to[out=150,in=0] (-0.5,0.2) --
cycle;}},
pics/bullet/.default={fill=white},font=\sffamily]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=YAW]
  \draw (0,0) -- (6,0) pic[pos=0.15,rotate=180]{bullet}
  pic[pos=0.325,rotate=135]{bullet} pic[pos=0.5,rotate=180]{bullet}
  pic[pos=0.675,rotate=225]{bullet} pic[pos=0.85,rotate=180]{bullet};
 \end{scope}
 \node[below right] at (0,0|-YAW.south) {YAW};
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=PRECESSION,yshift=-2.5cm]
  \draw plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=0:5.05,samples=301] ({\t+0.15*sin(\t*1200)},
  {\t*cos(\t*1200)/8});
  \draw (0,0) -- (6,0) pic[pos=0.9,rotate=150]{bullet={fill=gray!50}}
  pic[pos=0.9,rotate=225]{bullet};
 \end{scope}
 \node[below right] at (0,0|-PRECESSION.south) {PRECESSION};
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=NUTATION,yshift=-5cm]
  \draw plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=0:360,samples=101] 
  ({1+0.6*cos(\t)+0.2*cos(10*\t)},
  {0.6*sin(\t)+0.2*sin(10*\t)});
  \draw plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=0:360,samples=101] 
  ({4+0.7*cos(\t)+0.2*cos(10*\t)},
  {0.7*sin(\t)+0.2*sin(10*\t)});
  \fill (1,0) circle[radius=2pt] (4,0) circle[radius=2pt];
 \end{scope}
 \node[below right] at (0,0|-NUTATION.south) {NUTATION};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, This is amazing.